# STATIC IP for SOFAP_STA in ESP-IDF

Tags: esp-idf, static-ip-address

I'm using the esp-idf example from softap_sta and I would like to know if it is possible to make the esp32 receive an ip static IP address instead of a dynamic IP.

I tried using the esp_netif_set_ip_info() based in example [static_ip_example_main](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/protocols/static_ip/main/static_ip_example_main.c)  function but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When calling the static_ip function in the sta_connected event it shows this error:

E (3769) esp_netif_lwip: stop dhcp client call with NULL API E (3769) WiFi SoftAP: Failed to stop dhcp client